# Intend a paragraph after a subheading within a list

Tags: html

I am trying to compose an unordered list where each item has a heading, followed by a description, but I want the description content to be indented so that if it wraps to the next line, the new line will be in line with where the description text started on the previous line. Whenever I try inserting divs within the div, it always starts the description text on a new line.

```
The following is a list:
     Item 1 - This is the description of item 1. When this description wraps to the next line, 
              it should wrap to the same indentation the first line started on.
     Item 2 - This is the description of item 2. When this description wraps to the next line, 
              it should wrap to the same indentation the first line started on.
     Item 3 - This is the description of item 3. When this description wraps to the next line, 
              it should wrap to the same indentation the first line started on.
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a definition list of HTML.

```
<dl>
<dt>Item 1-</dt>
<dd>This is the description of item 1. When this description wraps to the next line, it should wrap to the same indentation the first line started on.</dd>
</dl>
```

Description List or Definition List displays elements in definition form like in a dictionary.
dl tag defines the description list.
dt tag defines data term.
dd tag defines data definition (description).